# evaluation matrix for CNN model, which one is more important?

Tags: matrix, evaluation, conv-neural-network

why would many paper only include the best accuracy, instead of loss. doenst mean loss is not important for comparision of different models？

what is the core difference between these two concepts? suppose i am 90% sure of data[0] is class A. it return ofc data0 is class A. and the loss?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the cost is decreasing the model is showing improvements (Im omitting the possibility of over-fitting just for this case). Although cost and accuracy normally have a inverse proportionality relationship, but you may note that accuracy is a summation of zero-one errors whereas cost is a summation of floating point numbers. Therefore, 0.001% decrease in the cost does not necessarily mean 0.001% increase in the accuracy. Increasing the accuracy is much harder when the decrement in cost is intangible (the cost is very close to a local minima)

For your question:

> suppose i am 90% sure of data[0] is class A. it return ofc data0 is class A. and the loss?

Generally while focusing on whether the model is working, you calculate in terms of the accuracy (or some other metric depending on the problem). As mentioned above the proportionality varies the accuracy interpretation exactly mentions your thought process of it definitely returning "data0" but the same can not be said of loss.

Comment: Thank you first for deep understand for two concept. And still what is more important to compare different models, if set weights to give models scores. what would be better matrix

Comment: Could you explain a bit more> im not sure i quite understand your question.